# Where can I find the drivers for the HP Officejet 6200 Series Fax?

Tags: windows-xp, fax, hp-officejet, print-drivers

Can someone tell me how to install the HP Officejet 6200 Series Fax? I can no longer find the original setup CD and I can't find the drivers online. I am using Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 1):

After your update regarding OS [XP Full Install](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=391212&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=391210&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1093)  Later operating systems do not have the full suite while earlier versions (XP for example) do.  Are you using the linked package?  Do you do a full installation?

Is this a 6210?  Exact HP6200 model might help.

You can alos contact HP and request replacement media but there will be a fee

Comment: I tried them and they don't install the fax printer

Comment: What OS are you using  That might help others make suggestions.

Comment: Windows XP Pro.